# Can an implicit conversion "mutate" its target object?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I'd like to find a way for an implicit "input" conversion in C# to be able to mutate the target object of the conversion, rather than replace it with a new object.

Scenario: I have a wrapper type `ObservableValue` which looks like this:

```
public struct ObservableValue
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    public ObservableValue(int value)
    {
        mValue = value;

        // must initialize all members since this is a struct
        ValueChanged = null;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return mValue; }
        set { if (mValue != value) { mValue = value; RaiseValueChanged(); } }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(ObservableValue value)
    {
        return value.mValue;
    }

    private RaiseValueChanged()
    {
        var handler = ValueChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private int mValue;
}
```

As you can see the class supports implicit conversion to its wrapped type, so I can write this:

```
ObservableValue myValue = new ObservableValue(6);
int result = myValue * 7; // 42
```

I'd also like to allow implicit input conversions (from the wrapped type to the wrapper), so that I can write this:

```
myValue = 42;
```

So I tried a standard implicit conversion operator:

```
public static implicit operator ObservableValue(int value)
{
    return new ObservableValue(value);
}
```

The problem here is that the conversion creates a new `ObservableValue`, which means any subscribers to the `ValueChanged` event are now lost. **Is there any way to support an implicit "input" conversion in such a way that existing object state is preserved?**

(This "scenario" may seem strange, but I've stripped it down significantly. The real scenario is more complicated; the key is that my wrapper class has other state that must be preserved when the object is assigned via an implicit conversion.)

Comment: The fact that you've got a *struct* with an event is deeply suspicious to start with. Mutable value types are generally a bad idea, and for an event to work it *must* mutate something (to record the subscription). Additionally, your implicit conversion is just from `int` - how could it "know" which observable value it was meant to be with? (There's no *target* of a conversion - just the source.) Finally, using an implicit conversion for this sounds like a really bad idea - why don't you just set the `Value` property?

Comment: @JonSkeet There is no outside requirement for it to be a struct. My real goal here is to create a helper class which wraps a type and provides the `ValueChanged` event. I have several classes containing `string`, `int`, etc. properties, and each of them must provide an on-change event to other code. I could simply use the `.Value` property as you suggest, and skip conversions, but I was hoping to find a way to support it implicitly so the observable wrapper "looks" just like its wrapped primitive. Is there a better way to go about this? I'm open to any alternatives.

Comment: Just use the `Value` property. It will make your life much, much simpler. Avoid code that tries to be "clever" - aside from anything else, even if you *could* do this, I would find it thoroughly confusing as it goes against all the normal conventions of conversions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the advice. I think it depends on whose "conventions" though; it might not be counterintuitive to someone from a C++ background, used to assignment operators and the `mutable` keyword. To an outsider using the code, the wrapper should simply look like any other primitive value, except that it has a built-in on-change event. They generally (if I've done my job right) would not need to care about the implementation. I'll reluctantly stick to `.Value` for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Anyone who tries to write .NET code as if they're using C++ is going to have a bad time anyway. Don't try to emulate the idioms of one platform in another - it never works out well, in my experience. Don't forget that you never change the value of an `int` itself (for example) - you change the value of the *variable*. That's a very significant difference.